# GGPLOT Changing Y Axis for factored column from (0-1) scale to Count

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the Y axis from the (0-1) scale to the actual count but not sure how to do that.

```
Teams_by_Level <- structure(list(Manager = c("Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", 
"Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", 
"Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", "Bob Beno", 
"Dylan Tracy", "Dylan Tracy", "Dylan Tracy", "Dylan Tracy", "Dylan Tracy", 
"Dylan Tracy", "Dylan Tracy", "Dylan Tracy", "Dylan Tracy", "Dylan Tracy"
), Level = c("MR4", "MR4", "IC2", "IC4", "MR4", "IC4", "IC4", 
"MR4", "MR4", "MR4", "MR4", "MR4", "MR3", "MR3", "MR3", "IC4", 
"IC2", "MR4", "MR4", "MR4", "IC2", "IC2", "IC3", "MR3", "IC3"
), Manager_Simple = c("Beno", "Beno", "Beno", "Beno", "Beno", 
"Beno", "Beno", "Beno", "Beno", "Beno", "Beno", "Beno", "Beno", 
"Beno", "Beno", "Tracy", "Tracy", "Tracy", "Tracy", "Tracy", 
"Tracy", "Tracy", "Tracy", "Tracy", "Tracy")), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Teams_by_Level$Level<- factor(Teams_by_Level$Level, 
                                   levels = c("IC2","IC3","IC4", "MR2", "MR3","MR4"))

#create plot
ggplot(data = Teams_by_Level, 
                       aes(x = Manager_Simple,
                          #y = Level,
                           fill = Level)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count", position = "fill")
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `position = "stack"` and not `position = "fill"`.

Comment: That fixed it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change from "fill" to "stack" in the geom_bar()

Answer by @Jon Spring

```
                       aes(x = Manager_Simple,
                          #y = Level,
                           fill = Level)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count", position = "stack")
```

Comment: I think you can  just as well very simply use only `+ geom_bar()` (empty call)